# CATransition private api

Tags: iphone

Just wonder on ios6
@"suckEffect",@"cube",@"oglFlip",@"pageCurl",@"rippleEffect"  ,@"pageUnCurl"

which one is private and rejected by app store?

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Naturally, the ones defined in the `CoreAnimation` framework are the ones that are public, and are OK:

```
// CAAnimation.h

/* Common transition types. */

CA_EXTERN NSString * const kCATransitionFade
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING (__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_2_0);
CA_EXTERN NSString * const kCATransitionMoveIn
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING (__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_2_0);
CA_EXTERN NSString * const kCATransitionPush
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING (__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_2_0);
CA_EXTERN NSString * const kCATransitionReveal
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING (__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_2_0);
```

These types are all private, rejected by apple:

```
NSString *const kCATransitionCube = @"cube";  
NSString *const kCATransitionSuckEffect = @"suckEffect"; 
NSString *const kCATransitionOglFlip = @"oglFlip";  
NSString *const kCATransitionRippleEffect = @"rippleEffect";  
NSString *const kCATransitionPageCurl = @"pageCurl"; 
NSString *const kCATransitionPageUnCurl = @"pageUnCurl";   
NSString *const kCATransitionCameraIrisHollowOpen = @"cameraIrisHollowOpen";
NSString *const kCATransitionCameraIrisHollowClose = @"cameraIrisHollowClose";
```